# How to write datetime with microseconds to Cassandra with Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, timestamp, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to stream a specific date format into a Cassandra `datetime` column.

My incoming date format is in the following date format:

```
"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"

e.g. "2021-05-18T11:12:13.123456"
```

My Cassandra table is:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (

  id text,
  timestamp timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)

)
```

The ingestion of my Spark job is the following:

```scala
val df = spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkahost)
    .option("subscribe", kafkatopic)
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
    .load()

val jsonSchema = StructType(
      List(
        StructField("id", StringType, true),
        StructField("timestamp", StringType, true)
      )
    )

val cassandraDF = df
    .withColumn("value", col("value").cast(StringType)),
    .withColumn("json", from_json(col("value"), jsonSchema))
    .select("json.*")
```

At this point, `cassandraDF` has two columns `id` and `timestamp`, both are `StringType`.

Then, writing to Cassandra is also quite simple:

```scala
cassandraDF
    .writeStream
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .option("keyspace", cassandra_keyspace)
    .option("table", cassandra_table)
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoints/cassandra")
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
```

When I stream data, I get the following `ERROR`:

> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:297)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:193)
>
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Invalid date: 2021-05-18T11:12:13.123456**

So I tried streaming other date formats. For example one without the microseconds:

```
"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"

e.g. "2021-05-18T11:12:13"
```

and that streams **without any problem**. This date date format gets accepted.

My question is:

- How can I format my date so that I can stream microseconds to Cassandra via Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra supports only millisecond resolution for timestamp type. By default it's not allowed to write string into timestamp field, but Spark Connector having implicit transformations like [this](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/42937e1ed01dd5aefb37fea38dbafc49ed44250e/driver/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/types/TypeConverter.scala#L348).  And if you look into [this source code](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/driver/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/types/TimestampParser.scala), you'll see that it supports only parsing from timestamp with milliseconds.

So the solution would be to convert your `timestamp` column from `string` to Spark `timestamp` (only on Spark 3.x [where support for microseconds resolution was added](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/07/22/a-comprehensive-look-at-dates-and-timestamps-in-apache-spark-3-0.html)):

```scala
val cassandraDF = df
    .withColumn("value", col("value").cast(StringType)),
    .withColumn("json", from_json(col("value"), jsonSchema))
    .select("json.*")
    .withColumn("timestamp"), $"timestamp".cast("timestamp")
```

But anyway it will be stored in Cassandra with milliseconds only.

Comment: I am using Spark 2.4.x. I tried the solution of the string only containing milliseconds instead of microseconds and it worked. For my use case that is enough. Interesting is that when I do a `SELECT` in the Cassandra timestamp column, it displays microseconds. So now even when I ingest milliseconds, the output of the `SELECT` is something like this `2021-05-19 08:23:16.858000+0000`.

Comment: regarding the displaying - it's just very bad default in the `cqlsh`, because `%f` format in Python is printing with microseconds: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/pylib/cqlshlib/formatting.py#L115

Comment: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html#working-with-timestamps - documentation about timestamps that says that it's in milliseconds.  Sometime it's confusing because the timestamp that is assigned to value (write time) is in microseconds